# autorun.inf - not showing my program in the list of options?

Tags: windows-7, usb, autorun

I have a program thats called myApp.exe

My inf file is this:

```
[autorun]
open=myApp.exe
action=Run myApp
icon=myApp.exe
label=myApp
```

The icon works and the label. But it won't show the .exe in the list of options when you plug the USB drive in. Everything is in the root. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Autorun.inf** files are handled differently in Windows 7 to [improve security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/improvements-to-autoplay). Only removable optical media, i.e. [type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) `DRIVE_CDROM`, can specify an AutoRun (`open`) task.

- See: [MSDN | Autorun.inf Entries: Open/UseAutoPlay](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/autorun-cmds#useautoplay)

Comment: I know it won't actually execute the program. But I just wanted it to appear on the list of options along with things like Import pictures and videos and Open folder to view files. Is this not possible anymore?

Comment: That is correct. It will not appear on the list.