# Autorun.inf in Windows 8/8.1 for USB Drives

Tags: windows-8, usb, windows-8.1, autorun, autoplay

I have created a file named autorun.inf to make one of my software setup run when the usb is plugged into Windows 8/8.1 OS .

This is my autorun.inf code:

```
[AutoRun]
shellexecute="Mem.exe //It would be nice if i could add path to this like my Doc//mem.exe
UseAutoPlay=1
```

Is there any software that let's us to create auto-run files for USB Sticks?

Is there any way to add new options in right click menu only on my USB window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [autorun.inf - not showing my program in the list of options?](http://superuser.com/questions/421801/autorun-inf-not-showing-my-program-in-the-list-of-options)

Comment: @and31415 So there's no way in solving this issue . Anyway i got a clarification from the link you provided .

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8 does not have a autorun on usb for security reasons. But there is a workaround in [this](http://www.visualdesigning.com/articles/how-to-create-autorun-usb-drive/) article. You need to separate the usb into two partitions, and make Windows believe one is a CDROM. This will bypass the security on windows.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would be just a teaser.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.